# Bot Framework: Using SIP in Skype bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype

I wanted to know if it's possible to use a `sip:` or `tel:` endpoint in a Skype bot. So something like a hero card having a button called "Contact us" and the button having hyperlink like sip:support@something.com and clicking on the button would open a new Skype chat window.

I tried doing the above but the button is not clickable in Skype. So is there a way to achieve this?

**Update:** I figured out one bit. It works if I use `skype:` instead of `sip:` or `call:`. However, it makes a phone call straightaway instead of opening a chat window to chat. How do I default it to chat than a Skype call.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. `sip:` isn't the right thing to use. `skype:` is. But using `skype:` would default to a Skype call being made, so you would need a `?chat` parameter.

My code looked something like:

> builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'skype:support@something.com?chat', 'Contact Us'),